# How parse lu, li tags with jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I know, there are a lot of questions on this, but no answer helped me.
Trying to parse football news from one famous ukrainian portal and put to my listview.

I parsed "news-feed" class:

```
 class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://football.ua/england.html").get();
            Elements elements = document.select(".news-feed");

            for (Element element : elements){
                Element element1 = element.select("a[href]").first();
                hashMap.put(element.text(), element1.attr("abs:ahref"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can find their rss feed in xml or json form?had you tried for that?

Comment: then get that ...parse it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Elements elements = document.select("article.news-feed");
```

Instead of

```
Elements elements = document.select(".news-feed");
```

EDIT: comparing my code to yours, I see good differences, firstly and I think more important, you accumulate the read values in a HashMap, I in a StringBuffer. Then I connect and go this way:

```
try {

doc = Jsoup.connect("http://football.ua/england.html").userAgent("yourPersonalizedUA").timeout(0).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
topicList = doc.select("article.news-feed");

for (Element topic : topicList) {
    myString += topic.html();
}} catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("io - "+e); }

buffer.append(myString);
```

Then, if everything worked

```
return buffer.toString();
```

Presuming you've already stated at the beggining:

```
private Document doc;
private String myString;
private StringBuffer buffer;
private Elements topicList;
```

Not shure if this helps, maybe can lead into a new perspective. Have you succeeded parsing another page with your code?

Comment: doesn't help. still like was

Comment: Here worked. Maybe it's Jsoup version, mine is 1.7.3. If you want I can send you a screenshot.

Comment: Will try 1.7.3 version.

Comment: Edited my answer with new snippets.

Comment: Have solved by myself:)
If somebody need, here is code:
 Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://football.ua/england.html").get();
                Elements elements = document.select(".news-feed > ul > li");
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    Element link = element.select("a[href]").first();
                    hashMap.put(element.text(), link.attr("abs:href"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return hashMap;