# Parsing a simple HTML in Java

Tags: java, html

How to parse a part of an html? For example I want to show "Here are OL list items:"

The example "file.html":

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>This is some html. Look, here's an <u>underline</u>.</p>
<p>Look, this is <em>emphasized.</em> And here\\'s some <b>bold</b>.</p>
<p>Here are UL list items:
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<p>Here are OL list items:
<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

What I tried was

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

but it shows the whole html code

Comment: In your html code, you haven't mentioned the `<html>` tag at the start and end of the document. Without any root element, it won't work. Put the tag and open the file again.

Comment: If the **html** is on the web (i did not test if it works from assets folder), you can use a library like JSoup. Here is an example, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254582/5885018

Comment: In order to easily get values from an HTML file you can use regular expressions to achieve so.

Answer (score 0):

> **Learn to parse HTML Pages on Android with JSoup**
>
> When you make Android applications, you can have to parse HTML data or
>   HTML pages got from the Web. One of the most known solution to make
>   that in Java is to use JSoup Library. Like said on the official
>   website of JSoup : “It is a Java library for working with real-world
>   HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and
>   manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like
>   methods.”
>
> JSoup can be used in Android applications and we’re going to study how
>   to parse an HTML Page on Android with JSoup. You can discover the
>   tutorial in video on Youtube :
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqMIcugsCFc
>
> First, you need to add the JSoup dependency in your Gradle build file
>   :
>
> ```
> compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
> ```
>
> For our example, we are going to download the content of the SSaurel’s
>   Blog and display all the links of the main page. To download the
>   content of a website, JSoup offers the connect method and then a get
>   method. This last method works synchronously. So, we should call these
>   methods in a separated Thread. Our application will have just a simple
>   layout with a Button to launch the download of the website and a
>   TextView to display the links.
>
> It will have the following form :
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>   tools:context="com.ssaurel.jsouptut.MainActivity">
>
>   <Button
>     android:id="@+id/getBtn"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Get website"
>     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
>
>   <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/result"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Result ..."
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
>     android:layout_below="@id/getBtn"
>     android:textSize="17sp"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> In the main Activity of the application, we are going to get instances
>   of the Button and the TextView from our layout. Then, we set a click
>   listener on the Button to start the download of the website when the
>   user will click it.
>
> In the getWebsite() method, we create a new Thread to download the
>   content of the website. We use the connect() method of the Jsoup
>   object to connect the application to the website, then we call the
>   get() method to download the content. These calls return a Document
>   object instance. We have to call the select() method of this instance
>   with the query to get all the links of the content. This query returns
>   an Elements instance and finally, we have just to iterate on the
>   elements contained in this object to display the content of each link
>   to the screen.
>
> At the end of our separated Thread, we refresh the UI with the links
>   got from the website. This refresh is embedded inside a runOnUiThread
>   call because it’s forbidden to refresh the UI elements inside a
>   separated thread.
>
> The code of the MainActivity has the following form :
>
> ```
> package com.ssaurel.jsouptut;
>
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
> import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
> import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
> import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>   private Button getBtn;
>   private TextView result;
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
>     getBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
>     getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View view) {
>         getWebsite();
>       }
>     });
>   }
>
>   private void getWebsite() {
>     new Thread(new Runnable() {
>       @Override
>       public void run() {
>         final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
>
>         try {
>           Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ssaurel.com/blog").get();
>           String title = doc.title();
>           Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
>
>           builder.append(title).append("\n");
>
>           for (Element link : links) {
>             builder.append("\n").append("Link : ").append(link.attr("href"))
>             .append("\n").append("Text : ").append(link.text());
>           }
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>           builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
>         }
>
>         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>           @Override
>           public void run() {
>             result.setText(builder.toString());
>           }
>         });
>       }
>     }).start();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Last step is to run the application and to enjoy the final result with
>   all the links of the SSaurel’s blog displayed on the screen :
>
> [image]
>
> https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f